# Navigate between text box using PDFMiner

Tags: python, pdfminer

I refer to the code that has been provided by PDFminer:

```
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine, LTFigure


def parse_layout(layout):
    """Function to recursively parse the layout tree."""
    for lt_obj in layout:
        print(lt_obj.__class__.__name__)
        print(lt_obj.bbox)
        if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox):
            print(lt_obj.get_text())
        elif isinstance(lt_obj, LTFigure):
            parse_layout(lt_obj)  # Recursive


fp = open(r'C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\XX.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)

rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    parse_layout(layout)
```

This code is able to read and print the layout of the documents. For example,

LTTextBoxHorizontal
(21.36, 452.28479999999996, 96.2544, 461.74559999999997)
MARKS AND NUMBER

I specifically filter only text boxes to be printed. **I was wondering if there is anyway to print specific text boxes or navigate through the text boxes. For example, I want to print the 3rd box from the top, or 5th box from the current text box.**

Would greatly appreciate is anyone could help! :)

Comment: So sort those results on their x or y position.